# Clustering methods sensitivity to correlation of data structure?

Tags: machine-learning, clustering, svm

I have seen clustering based upon different metrics. However, none of them sees inherent correlation structure in the data. I could use Mahalanobis distance to account correlation in population level but it does not account group correlations. Or maybe I could manually add groups as covariates which should account for correlation structure.

Are clustering methods sensitive to correlated data structure(i.e. longitudinal or hierarchical structure)? When I say hierarchical structure, I mean at least 2 level structure(i.e. A is nested in B and B is nested in C).